# Z-Index issues bootstrap modals and google chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, z-index

We're working with an application and I've experienced this is a chrome only issue. I read in one thread on GitHub that I can't seem to find now, that this issue has to do with when any of the elements move on the screen when you have multiple transparent items. This seems to fit with what I've experienced. Has anyone else come across this issue or have a solution. I've researched it a bit but I was unable to find any answers, mainly because I wasn't sure how to describe it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is definitely an issue that we are also experiencing. We are using bootstrap and angularjs, we have a ticket with many examples one of which is linked here:
[Weird modal issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVd9z.png)

All the occurrences occur with a modal, and our modals move from the top down. No solutions yet but will update if we discover one.